# How to correctly save the changes to Entity with Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to write the proper implementation of PUT-action. I have a basic Model class (let's call it Model).

```
public class Model
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public User Creator { get; set; }
}
```

Creator is a required navigation property which references the User entity by foreign key.
Also I have a simple DTO class for my Model which is being posted from the Client.

```
public class ModelDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the DTO class doesn't contain the Creator reference because we don't need to update it from the Client.

And here's the PUT-action. It is based on the template which Visual Studio scaffolded for me. I just added the Automapper call to map my DTO to Model.

```
    // PUT: api/Models/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutModel(int id, ModelDTO modelDTO)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != Model.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var model = Mapper.Map<Model>(modelDTO); // i've just added this
        db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ModelExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

The problem is SaveChangesAsync method crashes with Db validation error 'The Creator field is required.'.
Technically I understand that Creator is null because I've created the new Model instance and EF doesn't know whether I want to set the Creator to null or ignore it. I need to declare somehow that I don't want to set the Creator. I just want to update the Name (or other future scalar properties). So how to do it correctly without loading (including) the Navigation Property data?
Is there some common best-practice approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, once you throw the crap that the scaffolder generated for you, maybe you can try writing some useful code and increasing your chances of having some working solution.

You can start by getting rid of the `Id` property from your DTO/viewmodel => this comes from elsewhere (the route segment), so it shouldn't be part of your update view model:

```
public class ModelDTO
{
    // The name is required => make sure that your DTO
    // respects this requirement as well before even
    // reaching your backend
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Cool, now you can proceed and write the code for your PUT controller action:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(int id, ModelDTO modelDTO)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    // Get the model that you are trying to update from the DB
    // using the id:
    var model = db.Models.Find(id);

    if (model == null)
    {
        // the id that was provided as parameter doesn't exist in the DB =>
        // we don't need to go any further, just let the client know
        // by returning 404
        return NotFound();
    }

    // set the properties that you want to update (only Name in your case)
    // of course when you have more complex models you might consider using
    // AutoMapper to take care of this part, but for the purposes of this
    // demonstration you don't need it:
    model.Name = modelDTO.Name; 

    // Now save the changes back to your database
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

OK, so the thing to always remember here is the following:

> The first thing a developer should do when some tool is trying to write the code in his place is to simply throw this tool/code away and start doing his job (which in the case of a developer is to write code).

Comment: The thing is - your code doesn't solve the problem. SaveChangesAsync() will still throw the exception 'The Creator field is required', because due to lazy loading the Creator object is not loaded when you return the object using Models.Find().

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to update the Name (or other future scalar properties). So how to do it correctly without loading (including) the Navigation Property data? Is there some common best-practice approach?

so you want to update some specific fields and in your case `Name` field

```
 //// find your model 
 var entity = db.Models.Find(id);
 entity.Name=modelDTO.Name; 
 /// set modified property
 db.Entry(entity).Property(c => c.Name).IsModified = true     
 await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Yep, I can do that. But the problem is when the set of properties grows I'll have to manually enumerate all the properties and set IsModified to true for them. That kills all the automation :(